# Unity not allowing me to use Screen.safeArea

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen, iphone-x

I am trying to adjust the UI in my game to properly fit on the screen of an iPhone X.

In my code I am attempting to code the line `return Screen.safeArea`

However 'safeArea' is highlighted red and when I hover over the error with my cursor a message is displayed saying "error CS0117: 'UnityEngine.Screen' does not contain a definition for 'safeArea'".

I dont understand why I'm getting this error because according to Unity's documentation UnityEngine.Screen does contain a definition for safeArea.

Any inclination or idea as to why I am running into this error?

Also, I am working with Unity 2017.2.0f3

As per comments bellow, code as been asked for.

```
private Screen ReturnSafeArea(){return Screen.safeArea}
```

as I tried saying, the code has nothing to do with it. Even in this simplistic instance of the use of Screen.safeArea, safeArea is listed as not a definition of UnityEngine.Screen.

[image]

[image]

Hovering over safeArea displays the following message

> "'Screen' does not contain a definition for 'safeArea"

Comment: If you could post the code that is causing this error, and the exact error message we can help you better.

Comment: The code is as stated above. Im just trying to return the safe area but safeArea is highlighted red and im told its not a definition of UnityEngine.

Comment: Is the method just that one line? If it is, then this is a very interesting problem, at least to me.

Comment: just added a photo, its not a problem on my end for having poorly programmed. Its just not allowing me to use safeArea

Comment: Despite the lengthy comments required to solve this, I'm giving a +1 because while there were problems with the original question, the end result is a question that is very useful, as the introduction of this field was added in a *minor post-release patch* and not noted in the documentation.

Comment: its funny cause I added my Unity version into the original description of the question yet we all, including myself, overlooked it. Could have been solved hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Screen.screenArea` is of type `Rect` and your method is defined as returning a value of type `Screen`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-safeArea.html

One way to correct this:

```
private Rect ReturnSafeArea(){
    return Screen.safeArea;
}
```

Additionally, the field was added in [2017.2.0p1 (Nov 6)](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases/2017.2.0p1) and you're on [2017.2.0f3 (Oct 3)](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta/unity2017.2.0f2). Link is for 0.2, but 0.f3 does not have its own page, so likely was made either the same day or very shortly after.

Comment: all im trying to do is return Screen.safeArea and safeArea is highlighted red. Whats so complicated about that?

Comment: I think you got confused by the word write and assumed I was attempting to write to the safeArea. I meant write the line of code, so I changed the wording of my question to prevent any further confusion. But my question still stands, i didnt ask what safeArea does, i asked why is Unity telling me its not a definition contained within UnityEngine.Screen

Comment: @fourthking What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Unity 2017.2.0f3

Comment: @fourthking Can you supply: (a) your actual code as text in your question and (b) a screenshot of your IDE with that code (as a reply here).

Comment: added both to the question description

Comment: @fourthking `Screen.screenArea` is of type `Rect` and your method is defined as returning a value of type `Screen`. This is a type error, not a "this does not exist" error.

Comment: @fourthking Also your code-as-text declares the method as both the `void` and `Screen` Types while your screenshot says `private Screen`

Comment: Thats not the problem here. If that was the problem then visual studio would tell me I'm trying to return a different value than the function is asking for, it wouldnt underline safeArea

Comment: *`Thats not the problem here`* No, that's exactly your problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: No its not. I copy and pasted exactly what you have (which is the same thing I have but just changing Screen to Rect in the function declaration) and it still doesnt fix my error. The error isnt what im returning, its that unity doesnt recognize safeArea and thats my problem. Why doesnt it recognize Screen.safeArea

Comment: I added a photo to the question as proof

Comment: @fourthking Ah! `Screen.safeArea` was added in 2017.2.0p1 (Nov 6) and you're on 2017.2.0f3 (Oct 3). You need to update. That was a *bitch* to track down, I had to google around for specific version patch notes to find it.

Comment: Yeah, raybarrera put that is their answer and I just checked the release notes for 2017.2.1 and there is a mention of safeArea. I think thats probably my problem, I need to upgrade my unity. Thanks for helping me work through this

Comment: @fourthking I didn't see his answer posted until after my comment and subsequent edit (due to the way SO notifies an active page of new content).

Comment: yeah no worries, the answer was posted not long before your comment

Answer (score 3):

I believe Screen.safeArea was added in a minor release of 2017.2, so 2017.2.0f3 would not have it. Try your code in 2017.2.1 and newer to confirm. It's too bad the documentation doesn't specify that.

Comment: I think you may be right. You mentioning that made me look up the release notes for version 2017.2.1 and there is a mention of safeArea. I'll perform the update and get back

Comment: This seems to be the most likely thing. I didn't even consider that. Good catch.

Comment: @TJWolschon I *had* considered it, but I had a lot of difficulty *tracking it down.* It's why I'd asked what version fourthking was using!